# Adding space at the beginning of a line

Tags: spacing

How can I add some blank characters at the beginning of a line? The point is to align text with the relevant text above, e. g. instead of:

> (a) text
>
> text

I would like to have:

> (a) text
>
> .....text

(Without the dots of course)

Comment: Search for `enumerate` and check if that’s what you want .

Answer (score 1):

An expandation of nidhin's comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \lipsum[2]

    \lipsum[3]
    \item \lipsum[4]

%...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]